# How can I fix 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input' error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm using [dolphin](https://phpdolphin.co) social networking script and I have more than one languages files with json and when I pass other language then if I click homepage or another link then google chrome gave me a this error line..I read same title of stackoverflow but I couldn't get out of business.

footnote: my script is php and I used `json_encode();` `utf8_encode();` but nothing happend because same time I have turkish character problem.

footnote2: I changed mysql character set too and again nothing happend

[image]

Console gave me a this error

```
feed:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (functions.js:2102)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at A (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4)
```

and my functions.js:2102 line

```js
// Request the page
$.ajax({
  url: pageurl,
  type: type,
  data: parameters,
  success: function(data) {
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    // Show the content
    $('#content').html(result.content);
    // Stop the loading bar
    stopLoadingBar();
    // Set the new title tag
    document.title = result.title;
    // Scroll the document at the top of the page
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
    load_modes();
    // Reload functions
    reload();
  }
});
```

end function of this line

```js
function liveLoad(pageurl, type, parameters) {
 // page url = request url
 // type = 1: POST; 0: GET;
 // parameters: serialized params
 cleanOldFid();
 startLoadingBar();
 
 if(type == 1) {
  var type = "POST";
 } else {
  var type = "GET";
 }

 // Request the page
 $.ajax({url: pageurl, type: type, data: parameters, success: function(data) {
  var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  // Show the content
  $('#content').html(result.content);
  // Stop the loading bar
  stopLoadingBar();
  // Set the new title tag
  document.title = result.title;
  // Scroll the document at the top of the page
  $(document).scrollTop(0);
  load_modes();
  // Reload functions
  reload();
 }});
 
 // Store the url to the last page accessed
 if(pageurl != window.location) {
  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl}, '', pageurl); 
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that the data parameter being returned in your success function is valid JSON? Seems like the error is being thrown by the jQuery.parseJSON() function.

You should add a console.log(data) at top of the success function to check and run the contents through an online JSON validator (see jsonlint).